# Time format on zsh

Tags: time, zsh

I'm trying to run the command

```
time -f "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys" ls -Fs
```

on my zsh but I get

```
zsh: command not found: -f
```

But I got this line of code from the man docs of time.

Is this an issue with zsh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `/usr/bin/time -f "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys" ls -Fs`

I found this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86193/command-not-found-when-trying-to-set-a-format-for-the-time-command)

Comment: A backslash can also be used to prevent the builtin version from being used: `\time -f "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys" ls -Fs`.

Comment: There is a standard way of preferring executable over built-in: `command time -f …`.

Comment: You can also use the `=` shortcut: `=time`.

Answer (score 7):

The `zsh` builtin `time` (as you've figured out by  now) doesn't take a `-f` option; rather, you set the value of the shell parameter `TIMEFMT`

```
$ TIMEFMT=$'\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys'
$ time ls -Fs
```